# Differentiability of a two-variable function in the origin

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
xy\cdot \log(xy)   & xy>0 \\
0    &xy \leq0
\end{cases}$$

From the definition of derivative I was able to prove that $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0) $. Now I have to verify if the function is differentiable in the origin, i.e. I have to verify that
$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$. My attempt was this:
if $hk<0$, then $f(h,k)=0$, and so the limit is verified; if $hk>0$ I have that
\begin{align}0 &\leq\bigg|\frac{f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\bigg|\\[1mm]
&=\bigg|\frac{hk\cdot \log(hk)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\bigg|\\[1mm]
&=\bigg|\frac{hk\cdot \log(|h|)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}+\frac{hk\cdot \log(|k|)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\bigg|\\[1mm]
&\leq \bigg|\frac{hk\cdot \log(|h|)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\bigg|+\bigg|\frac{hk\cdot \log(|k|)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\bigg|\\[1mm]
&\leq \bigg|h\cdot\log(|h|)\bigg|+\bigg|k\cdot \log(|k|)\bigg|\\[1mm]
&\rightarrow 0\end{align}
Then the function is differentiable in the origin. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems ok to me.